# Help with 人物{じんぶつ}像{ぞう}の特定{とくてい}. What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, words, syntax

I have problems understanding this sentence:

> ここでは一メートル以内にいようと人物像の特定、声の確認はあやふやになる。なにしろ童話の中の出来事だ

Particularly:

> 人物像の特定

My guess is that it is one specific point of a person. Would it be in this case 声?

A bit of context:

> 一時的にしろ、公園は有珠{ありす}の“森”になっている。ここでは一メートル以内にいようと**人物像の特定**、声の確認はあやふやになる。なにしろ童話の中の出来事だ

Translation attempt:
Though temporary this park became Alice's "forest". Even when being within one meters reach the specifics of a persons figure and voice become hazy.

Comment: @JACK Please don’t leave answers in the comment section.

Answer (score 2):

This 人物像の特定 means identifying what kind of person the speaker is seeing (e.g., "He looks like a brave knight in a silver armor", "He looks like a tired middle-aged businessperson", ...). By the way, 人物の特定 is identifying who he is (e.g., "He is John Smith").